# Receive multiple columns from one sql request in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a friend list function and I can't figure out how to correctly receive the values.

My code looks like this:

```
$getuid = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE  name = ? OR name = ?");
$getuid->bind_param("ss", $user, $friend);
$getuid->execute();
$getuid->bind_result($uid);
$getuid->fetch();
$getuid->close();
$resetpass = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `friendlist` SET `friend1`=?, `friend2`=?, `accept`=0");
$resetpass->bind_param("ss", $uid[0], $uid[1]);
```

With the first query I get exactly two uid values back. I want to use them in the second query. It seems like `bind_result` is not working, neither as array nor when using two values in `bind_result`. How can I do this using mysqli. I can't use `get_result` because I'm on PHP 5.2 .

Anyone able to help me?

Comment: How did you got exactly two uid columns back from your first query: `SELECT uid FROM users`?? isn't this only one column?

Comment: sorry, I meant two values...from one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally understood the concept of fetch.

In order to receive all the values I have to retrieve them in a while-loop.

Here is the solution:

```
$getuid = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE  name = ? OR name = ?");
$getuid->bind_param("ss", $user, $friend);
$arra = array();
$getuid->execute();
$getuid->bind_result($uid);
while ($getuid->fetch()) {
    $arra[] = $uid;
}
```

Now I can call the array values using `$arra[0]` and `$arra[1]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this. I have not tested it and there are probably even better ways to do this. I just tried the quickest change i could make to your original code to get it to work.

```
$query = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE  name = '".$user."' OR name = '".$friend."'";
$getuid = $mysqli->query($query);
if($uid = $getuid->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $query = "INSERT INTO friendlist SET friend1= '".$uid['uid'][0]."', friend2='".$uid['uid'][1]."', accept=0";
    $mysqli->query($query)
    }
$getuid->close();
```

Comment: This doesn't help me. Like i mentioned, I can't use `get_result`

Comment: sorry about that should have read better. Question: Can you get the $user from somewhere else such as cookie or session. One the insert i get $user from my session and it allows me to put into database in such a way that i know who ask for the friendship. Maybe a little about your table structure and I will help you.

Comment: I'm afraid not, I am using the sql database to store user data from my android app. I also store name and email in an sqlite database on my phone, this is only to check if the user is logged in (table gets destroyed on logout). I could just return the uid from the database aswell and put it into the sqlite base on login. But I was hoping this would not be neccessary.
Right now I am solving this problem by doing two queries for each uid. It works, but I was hoping to find a more elegant way, because they can be returned in one query, but I dont know how to retrieve them in PHP.

Comment: Take a look at the edit i made. This may not be quite as elegant, but should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but using `mysqli_query`is a high security risk. You didn't even escape the string. I will stick to my method for now...

Comment: thought you said the input was coming from were you stored it. if that was case you do not need to protect non user inputs for injections. sorry i mis understood you.

Comment: It's coming from an android app via POST parameters. So yes, people are inputting part of the values. It's no problem :)

Comment: take a look at this. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#102179)

Comment: This did not help, check my answer.